# Android HttpResponse error

Tags: android, timestamp, http-post, httpresponse

Application post with many variables, crash in:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

There are any limits for the kind of variable to post?
Post is pretty long and contains only Strings.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.tab.popup.SaveJourney.journey(SaveJourney.java:124)
at com.tab.TabLayout.udData(TabLayout.java:738)
at com.tab.TabLayout.access$3(TabLayout.java:719)
at com.tab.TabLayout$6.run(TabLayout.java:671)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Is this possible that error can cause by TimeStamp?

Comment: check the client and post object for null may be the client object was null

Comment: is not null, I'm checking it couple times before it will post. I had before issue with variable types. Some String just won't go pass until you treat them Uri decode ( or decode), but this error occurs from time to time. So I think that this is or timestamp , or some string, or geopoint.lattitude/longtitude.

Comment: paste the code of SaveJourney.journey and write some comment on 124 line

Comment: we found the reason, too weak wi-fi connection. there is a way to check a strength of the signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            //give message
        }
        ///do your stuff here
      } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        getRequest.abort();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();

    } finally {
    }
```

Comment: This can also happen if the request doesn't have any url mentioned